# Crontab bad minute

Tags: cron

I am trying to add multiple cron tasks in crontab.

Step 1

```
crontab -e
```

Step 2

```
* * * * * php /home/vagrant/project/artisan do:task 1 >> /dev/null 2>&1
1/3 * * * * php /home/vagrant/project/artisan do:task 2 >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Step 3 - Save

```
crontab":1: bad minute
```

if I remove the 1/3 to become

```
3 * * * * php /home/vagrant/project/artisan do:task 2 >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

it saves fine but I need the offset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I am using Laravel and i the task manager it parses

```
1/3 * * * *
```

perfectly fine but when using crontab I must use this format.

```
1-59/3 * * * *
```

Phew!!!

Schoolboy error!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For others that might run into this issue, it can be either of the following problems:

1. The error "crontab":1: bad minute" actually mentions the line where the problem is: Here the error is with line # 1
2. Check if the hard disk is completely filled. The crontab cannot write the changes even in that case. Happens often !